# How to set DisplayFormat on a Model property

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor, model

I have set the [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}")] on my field Deductible but it still not applying the display format. Can anyone help. TY

[image]

CSHTML.CS

```
public class Contact
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime HireDate { get; set; }
    //public List<Phone> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
    //public
    //Address Address { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}")]
    public decimal Deductible { get; set; }
```

CSHTML:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Contacts.Count; i++)
            <div class="col-sm">
                <label asp-for="@Model.Contacts[i].Deductible" class="control-label"> </label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.Contacts[i].Deductible class=" control-label" value="@Model.Contacts[i].Deductible">
            </div>
```

Comment: What do  you expect your Deductible look like? Do you want to display it without decimal places ? Do you want to see 232 and 114?

Comment: Well I kind of expected it to to display as currency with 2 decimal place i.e. $232.44

Comment: Got it...I have changed it to value="@Model.Contacts[i].Deductible.ToString("0.00")" and that is returning correctly in a POST. Thank you so much for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[DisplayFormat]` is  respected when you use `DisplayFor()` and `EditorFor`

Try:

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Contacts[i].Deductible)
```

OR

```
<input asp-for="@Model.Contacts[i].Deductible class=" control-label" value="@Model.Contacts[i].Deductible.ToString("C2")">
```

Result:

[image]

Or

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

and use

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Contacts[i].Deductible)
```

**Update**
If you use

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}")]
```

and

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Contacts[i].Deductible)
```

In the post you will get:
[image]

Comment: The piece of code above works fine when displaying but when a POST is done "0" is returned

But without the .ToString("C2") the POST returns Model.Contacts[i].Deductible correctly

Comment: @Mark C Is your post return  `$232.44` ? But your Deductible type is `decimal` .So it will be 0. The DisplayFormat is only change the display not the type.

Answer (score 1):

Setting input as

```
<input name="Contacts[@i].Deductible" class="control-label" type="text" value="@Model.Contacts[i].Deductible.ToString(" 0.00")">
```

will allow the value to be displayed as a 2 decimal value and can POST back as a 2 decimal value

Comment: If you don't need `$`, that's ok.

Comment: My update is another way to  POST back as a 2 decimal value, you can have a look .